# Does the memory get released when I throw an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, handler

I was debating with some colleagues about what happens when you throw an exception in a dynamically allocated class. I know that `malloc` gets called, and then the constructor of the class. The constructor never returns, so what happens to the `malloc`?

Consider the following example:

```
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "B::B()" << endl;
        throw "B::exception";
    }

    ~B()
    {
        cout << "B::~B()" << endl;          
    }
};

void main()
{
    B *o = 0;
    try
    {
        o = new B;
    }
    catch(const char *)
    {
        cout << "ouch!" << endl;
    }
}
```

What happens to the malloced memory `o`, does it leak? Does the CRT catch the exception of the constructor and deallocate the memory?

Cheers!
Rich

Comment: Short answer: Yes. See Cătălin Pitiș Answer for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A call to

```
new B();
```

resolves in two things:

- allocating with an operator new() (either the global one or a class specific one, potentially a placement one with the syntax `new (xxx) B()`)
- calling the constructor.

If the constructor throw, the corresponding operator delete is called.  The case where the corresponding delete is a placement one is the only case where a placement delete operator is called without the syntax ::operator delete().  `delete x;` or `delete[] x;` don't call the placement delete operators and there is no similar syntax to placement new to call them.

Note that while the destructor of B will **not** be called, already constructed subobjects (members or B and base classes of B) will be destructed before the call to operator delete.  The constructor which isn't called is the one for B.

Comment: Important addendum: The constructor for B did not run, there never was an object of that type. If there was a new() being called in the constructor of B before the exception was triggered, it is *not* being released - and you no longer have a pointer to that memory, so you cannot delete() it. *KEEP AWAY* from new() in constructors.

Comment: If you use RAII techniques (for example, with std::auto_ptr), new() in the constructors is not a big deal.

Comment: @DevSolar: All depends on where the result of new is stored.  If it is in a smart pointer, ether local to the constructor or a member of the class B or of its parents, that object will be destroyed and the memory allocated within the constructor of B but before the throwing of the exception will be freed.  Obviously if you do new Foo(); throw "bar", the memory will not be freed and the Foo will not be destroyed.  In a constructor or elsewhere.  I'll clarify that the destructor of B isn't called.

Comment: If the constructor throws the destructor is NOT (I repeat NOT) called. Only fully constructed members and any fully constructed base classes will have their constructor called.

Comment: @DevSolar: The memmory is released automatically (note the 'New Statement' [Which calls the constructor] never completes). If you were using a smart pointer it would not help as the constructor to the smart pointer would never be entered and thus would not help in the deallocation.

Answer (score 7):

When an exception is thrown from the constructor, the memory allocated by new is released, but the destructor of class B is not called.

Comment: Yes. Just to complement your answer... There's a good reason for the destructor not being called: The object was never created. Destructors are called only for objects that existed in a particular period of time. And those are the cases where the constructor completed successfully.

Comment: Yes, you're right. An object is considered created (therefore destructible) only after the constructor successfuly executes.

Comment: Note: The destrucotr of any fully constructed members and base class(s) are called.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your object, o, does not actually get constructed, and the memory allocated by new is freed.  As such, the destructor does not get called.  So you do NOT need to call:

```
delete o;
```

An interesting design pattern is RAII -- Resource Acquisition Is Initialization.  In this pattern, you use a constructor to encapsulate the acquisition of a resource, and release the resource in the destructor.  If the resource can not be acquired, you throw in the constructor -- much like your example.  Thus if you have a valid object, you have the resource.

If the object is constructed, then you have successfully acquired the resource.  This means that for the life of the object, you own the resource.  When the object is deleted, the resource is released.  If the object is never constructed, then you never acquired the resource.  See wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: Consequently, if the constructor has done _some_ resource acquisition work before whatever triggers the exception, it is that constructor's job to clean up before it throws.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ 2003 Standard 5.3.4/17 - New:

> If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable deallocation  function  can  be  found,  the  deallocation  function  is  called  to  free  the  memory  in  which the object was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the new-expression.  If  no  unambiguous  matching  deallocation  function  can  be  found,  propagating  the  exception does not cause the object’s memory to be freed.  [Note: This is appropriate when the called allocation function does not allocate memory; otherwise, it is likely to result in a memory leak.  ]

So there may or may not be a leak - it depends on whether an appropriate deallocator can be found (which is normally the case, unless operator new/delete have been overridden).In the case where there's a suitable deallocator, the compiler is responsible for wiring in a call to it if the constructor throws.

Note that this is more or less unrelated to what happens to resources acquired in the constructor, which is what my first attempt at an answer discussed - and is a question that is discussed in many FAQs, articles, and postings.

Comment: This was really intended to answer the (duplicate?) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674980/who-deletes-the-memory-allocated-during-a-new-operation-which-has-exception-in