# Understanding exceptions throwing by a constructor

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I'm reading Scott Meyers' *Effective C++* and he provided an example of a well-designed assignement operator. Here it is:

```
class Bitmap{ ... };
class Widget
{
    //...
private:
    Bitmap *pb;
};

Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs)
{
    Bitmap *pOrig = pb;
    pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.pb);
    delete pOrig;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, the explanation he gives right after the example is about how the code is exception-safe.

> Now, if `new Bitmap` throws an exception, pb (and the Widget it's
>   inside of) remains unchaged)

I don't understand that. How can we ever talk about unchanging here if throwing execeptions by a constructor leads us to UB (because operator `delete` will no be called on the pointer return by the `new` operator which results in an exception) ?

Comment: Constructors are allowed to throw exceptions and this doesn't cause UB. Not sure what you are getting at in your last paragraph.  When an exception is thrown, execution jumps to the `catch` handler for the exception, it does not continue onto `delete pOrig;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb As you can see, there is no any cathc clause in the example. So, the program will just be terminated....

Comment: @St.Antario: How do you know there's no catch? The example is not a complete program.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Well, there is no catch inside the operator= definition. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @St.Antario: Since there's no catch in the operator, the exception will be passed up the call stack. If there's no catch there, it will be passed up again, until you get to an appropriate catch, or until it is passed out of main, only then will a termination happen.

Comment: If the operator catches the exception inside, the caller can't tell if the assignment succeeded or not. That's why it's intentionally unhandled.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley So, we leave the exception handling to the client. That way, after throwing the exception, we passed out to the catch clause, therefore the original object remains unchanged. Do I understand it correctly now?

Answer (score 2):

If a constructor throws, [`operator new` will not keep the memory allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674980/who-deletes-the-memory-allocated-during-a-new-operation-which-has-exception-in?rq=1). This prevents the memory leak.

Note that a memory leak wouldn't be Undefined Behavior.

Comment: __Note that a memory leak wouldn't be Undefined Behavior.__ Not clear. I thought the memory leak is UB.