# C++: If I overload new operator, do I have to overload the delete operator too?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I was reading a question on SO and in one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675301/2711672), it has been mentioned as:

> If no unambiguous matching deallocation function can be found,
>   propagating the exception does not cause the object’s memory to be
>   freed.

So, if I just overload my `new` operator and not the `delete` operator, would any default `delete` operator be created and called; or, do I have to also write the `delete` operator explicitly.

Comment: When your overloaded `new` is successful without an exception or otherwise? If you have a particular scenario, please add that code sample in your question with some context.

Comment: This passage talks about placement new. The regular operator new always has a matching delete whether you overload something or not.

Comment: @n.m., I agree with what you said about regular new, what would be invoked for placement new? would there be any default or nothing gets invoked?

Comment: @Azeem, when I invoke new and the constructor throws an exception.

Comment: As the passage says, if matching opetator delete is not found, nothing gets invoked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What this means is that if you overload operator new with extra arguments, and not the corresponding delete with extra arguments, if an exception occurs in a constructor, no delete operator will be called.  On the other hand, if you're overloading the basic new (with no extra arguments), and an exception occurs, delete with no extra argument will be called, and that will be the default operator delete if you have not overloaded it.

Comment: Just to be explicit, so if I invoke new with some arguments, the delete  taking same arguments will be invoked, correct?

Comment: if (one of) the constructors invoked after the `operator new` function returns throws an exception, yes.